# Multi-select dropdown not aligned correctly

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a multi-select dropdown that works as I want it but the CSS is where have issues. 1. its not appearing inside the main select field when selected. its appearing outside. 2. the dropdown is overlaying above other elements. attached below is the screen shots.
i need help in correcting the CSS to make the selected option appear inside the main select field.

Heres the code for the component

```js
    import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
    const data = [
      {
        title: "issue tickets",
      },
      {
        title: "cancel booking",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor flight bookings",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor transactions",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor flight deals",
      },
      {
        title: "manage flight deals",
      },
      {
        title: "manage flight addons",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor packages",
      },
      {
        title: "manage packages",
      },
      {
        title: "manage custom trips",
      },
      {
        title: "manage trip enquiries",
      },
      {
        title: "manage package bookings",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor package deals",
      },
      {
        title: "manage package deals",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor visa enquiries",
      },
      {
        title: "manage visa enquiries",
      },
      {
        title: "manage visa consultancy",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor commercial deals",
      },
      {
        title: "manage commercial deals",
      },
      {
        title: "manage deals booked",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor affiliates",
      },
      {
        title: "manage affiliate accounts",
      },
      {
        title: "manage affiliate portal",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor Corporate requests",
      },
      {
        title: "manage Corporate requests",
      },
      {
        title: "monitor blogs"
      },
      {
        title: "manage blogs"
      },
      {
        title: "monitor newsletters"
      },
      {
        title: "monitor contact enquiries"
      },
      {
        title: "manage contact enquiries"
      },
      {
        title: "manage settings"
      },
      {
        title: "manage roles and permissions"
      },
      {
        title: "manage users"
      },
      {
        title: "manage margin settings"
      },
    ]
    
    const DealsPage = () => {
      const [contents, setContents] = useState([])
      const togref = useRef()
      const [view, setView] = useState(false)
    
      // this function toggles the selection box on and off on outside clicks
      useEffect(() => {
        togref && window.addEventListener('click', e => { togref.current !== null && !togref.current.contains(e.target) && setView(false) }, true)
      }, [])
    
      const HandleSelection = (val) => {
        const findData = contents.find(ele => ele === val)
        if (!findData) {
          // add the data
          setContents([...contents, val])
        } else {
          //remove the data
          const filters = contents.filter(ele => ele !== val)
          setContents(filters)
        }
      }
    
      const RemoveContent = val => {
        const filters = contents.filter(ele => ele !== val)
        setContents(filters)
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <div style={StyleSheet.container}>
            <div style={StyleSheet.showRoom}>
              {contents.map((item, i) => (
                <div style={StyleSheet.roomItem}>{item} <div onClick={() => RemoveContent(item)} style={StyleSheet.cancelButton}>x</div> </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={StyleSheet.container}>
            <div ref={togref} style={view ? StyleSheet.overall : StyleSheet.closeView}>
              {data.map((item, i) => (
                <div onClick={() => HandleSelection(item.title)} style={contents.includes(item.title) ? StyleSheet.datashown : StyleSheet.data} key={i}>{item.title}</div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setView(true)} style={StyleSheet.input}>--Select Multiple Options--</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    
    export default DealsPage

    
    const StyleSheet = {
      container: {
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: '30rem',
        margin: '5% auto'
      },
      closeView: { display: 'none' },
      overall: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '30rem',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        position: 'absolute',
        border: '1px solid lightgrey',
        top: '4rem',
        left: 0,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        display: 'block',
      },
      data: {
        padding: '0.3rem',
        borderBottom: '1px solid lightgrey',
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
      datashown: {
        padding: '0.3rem',
        borderBottom: '1px solid lightgrey',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        color: 'white',
      },
      input: {
        width: '100%',
        border: '1px solid lightgrey',
        padding: '1rem'
      },
      showRoom: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        gap: 10,
      },
      roomItem: {
        padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
        border: '1px solid lightgrey',
        borderRadius: '999px',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        gap: 20,
        fontSize: '0.8rem'
      },
      cancelButton: {
        borderRadius: '999px',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        padding: '0.01rem 0.5rem',
        cursor: 'pointer'
      },
    }
```

> Attached below is the output of how it looks

[image]

Attached below is how I want it to be inside the select field
[image]